# Creating a php mapper function

Tags: php, metaprogramming

I want to create a mapping function that takes an array, a key string and a value string. These two strings contain PHP code that I want to be evaluated against each element in the array.

The return values of these two calls should be used as keys and values in an associative array that will be returned.

E.g.

```
$assoc_list = my_mapper_function($list_of_people, 'id', 'full_name()');
```

Assuming that the list contains two people, Alice and Bob, who has id 4 and 5 - the return value should be something like:

```
[
   '4' => 'Alice Foo', 
   '5' => 'Bob Bar'
]
```

Any ideas on how to go around doing this?

For properties it is simple enough, because you can use bracket notation, but I want it to work with (chained) function calls as well.

Here is the code I've conjured up which unfortunately only works for properties:

```
public static function assoc_mapper($array, $key, $value) {
  $results = array();
  foreach ($array as $element) {
    $results[$element[$key]] = $element[$value];
  }
  return $results;
}
```

Comment: How does the input array look like?

Comment: It's irrelevant. It's just an array of elements, and I want the key and value strings evaluated against each element.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php ?

Comment: @NielsB. It is unclear what you want to do. But `array_walk()` seems what you are searching for..

Comment: How is it unclear what I want to do?

Comment: Seems like two separate questions. The mapping is trivial with `array_combine(array_map, array_map)` or a simple loop. The other question is about evaluating expressions, which is almost always a bad idea. Does it have to be strings? How about simple anonymous functions?

Comment: @deceze, I would like it to be short, elegant and to the point. Doing two iterations to build two arrays and then finally building the dictionary using array_combine produces a lot of code for something quite simple.

Comment: Who is voting down this question?

Comment: Be more specific. What is the second argument `id` doing? What should be checked? What should be mapped with what? Why don't you provide a simple input and your expected output example?

Comment: @Dan Lee, it doesn't matter. It's a list of elements. I want to run two expressions against each element. Is that hard to comprehend?

Comment: Good luck with that attitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have been able to do it so far is using `eval` which the official docs warn against. However, as I am not using user input, it's not a security risk.

```
public static function assoc_mapper($array, $key_expression, $value_expression) {
  $results = array();
  foreach ($array as $element) {
    $key = eval("return \$element->$key_expression;");
    $value = eval("return \$element->$value_expression;");
    $results[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $results;
}
```

If anyone has a niftier idea that still keeps the method call short, I'll be happy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Untested and just quickly hacked out, but I hope you get the idea. Instead of using literal `foo()->bar()` notation, go with a simplified `foo.bar` notation which you can handle yourself in various ways.

```
function getPropertyFromString($obj, $string) {
    if (is_array($obj) && array_key_exists($string, $obj)) {
        return $obj[$string];
    } else if (is_object($obj)) {
        if (isset($obj->$string)) {
            return $obj->$string;
        } else if (method_exists($obj, $string)) {
            return call_user_func(array($obj, $string));
        } else if (method_exists($obj, 'get' . ucfirst($string))) {
            return call_user_func(array($obj, 'get' . ucfirst($string)));
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function getValue($obj, $getter) {
    if (is_string($getter)) {
        return array_reduce(explode('.', $getter), 'getPropertyFromString', $obj);
    } else if (is_callable($getter)) {
        return call_user_func($getter, $obj);
    }
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid getter');
}

function mapper(array $array, $keyGetter, $valueGetter) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $result[getValue($value, $keyGetter)] = getValue($value, $valueGetter);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Examples:

```
mapper($array, 'id', 'name');      // simple properties
mapper($array, 'foo.bar', 'baz');  // nested properties
// super complex values
mapper($array, 'id', function ($obj) { return strtoupper($obj->foo(42)->bar()->baz); });
```